# Animation using views ids instead of relative positions

Tags: android, animation

So I am trying to implement animations in my app. I have some buttons nicely sorted within a RelativeLayout using `android:layout_above="id"` or `android:layout_toLeftOf="id"`, so I can easily change the margin between them and 
it's adaptable to every device' screen density.

My problem is, I try to implement animations for the buttons to come out from 
another one. It works, but it's hard to be as precise as it is in my RelativeLayout with tools such as `android:fromYDelta="--%p"`and `android:toYDelta="--%p"` (margin between buttons isn't the same everywhere, and I'm not sure that this will render the same for every device density).

So, is there a way to create an animation (via XML or programatically) with parameters like `android:startFromView="id"` or `android:translateToView="id"` ? If not, is it possible for me to implement such a method?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue. I extended my ImageButton to animate, then overrided its `onLayout(boolean,int,int,int,int)` method, and gave my extended class a private attribute : int [] location (size 2).
In it, I call `getLocationOnScreen(int[] location)` to get my button position on screen.

Finally, in my MainActivity, I just have to call my getter to know my button position on screen. I use

```
Animation anim = new TranslateAnimation(
Animation.ABSOLUTE,
btn.getLocation[1],
...
```

Hope this will help someone!